# css display table-cell horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css

Below here is the code that I wrote. I wanted a page with 3 table cells, where left one will be one table cell with 50% width of the page, and the right cell will be divided into 2 cells each with 50% height. The code below works partially fine.

The issue is the right 2 cells width gets reduced(screenshot attached). Can't figure out how to get the width to work :")

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%; height:100%;">
    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50%; border-style: ridge; height: 713px">
        <?php
            foreach($doctors as $entry)
            {
                echo '<div style="display: table-row; width=100%;">
                    <div style="display:table-cell; width:25%;">
                        <p style="margin-left:10px;">'.$entry["name"].'</p>
                    </div><div style="display:table-cell; width:20%;">
                        <p>'.$entry["id"].'</p>
                    </div><div style="display:table-cell; width:20%;">
                        <p>'.$entry["designation"].'</p>
                    </div><div style="display:table-cell;">
                        <p>'.$entry["salary"].'<button class="btn" name='.$entry["id"].' style="margin-left:100px; width;">Edit salary</button></p>
                    </div>
                </div>';
            }
        ?>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 100%;">
            <div style="display: table-row;">
                <div style="display: table-cell;">
                    <center>
                        <form style="border-style: ridge; height: 350px; padding-top: 17px;">
                            <label class="text" for="id">Enter ID: </label>
                            <input id="text-box" class="text" type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter id"><br>
                            <button id="btn" class="text">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div style="display: table-row;">
                <div style="display: table-cell;">
                    <center>
                        <form style="border-style: ridge; height: 350px; padding-top: 17px;">
                            <label class="text" for="id">Enter ID: </label>
                            <input id="text-box" class="text" type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter id"><br>
                            <button id="btn" class="text">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You should not nest a table-row in a table-cell. If you want nested tables you need to use a complete table structure, i.e. nest a `<table>` tag (or an element with `display="table"`) inside a table-cell, and then rows and cells inside that.

Comment: Just some more suggestions: If you are displaying tabular data, then use the proper table elements (`table`, `tr`, `td`, etc.) not just the `display: table-*` styles on divs. For layout you should look at the [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) instead of table. All styles should be in your style sheet not inline. And don't use `echo` inside loops, instead close and reopen the `<?php ?>` tags: `<?php foreach (...) { ?> <div> ... </div> <?php } ?>`